# material angular select dropdown renders totally outside app-root

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

https://material.angular.io/components/select/overview
the select dropdown renders totally outside app-root.
Basically it creats a div with class="cdk-overlay-container" which is appended as sibling of the app. I want the drop down to open at exactly where I embed `<mat-select>` tag. What am I missing.

Here is my code

```
import { Component, Input, Output, OnInit, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, ChangeDetectionStrategy, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <nav class="row navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-container">
            <div class="navbar__content">
                <mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select [formControl]="pc" panelClass="example-panel-{{pc.value}}">
                        <mat-option *ngFor="let panelColor of panelColors" [value]="panelColor.value">
                        {{ panelColor.viewValue }}
                        </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                </mat-form-field>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="main-page">
      NAVBAR ENDED MAIN PAGE STARTS
    </div>
    `,
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.scss' ],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
})
export class AppComponent  {
  private pc = new FormControl('red');
  private panelColors = [
    {value: 'red', viewValue: 'red'},
    {value: 'blue', viewValue: 'blue'},
    {value: 'green', viewValue: 'green'}
  ];
}
```

I created a stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-byq8u1)

Answer (score 7):

That's because you're missing a theme.

Add the following line to the top of your `styles.scss` or declare a theme (read the [guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming#defining-a-custom-theme) for more info):

```css
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css';
```

Comment: `cdk-overlay-container` is generated outside `app-root`, how adding theme will fix this ?

Comment: @AnkitPrajapati That's because the styles are then inserted into a `<style>` tag inside the `<body>` tag.

Comment: 3 hours of browsing and this solved. I am going to take deeper look on theme and figure out why this is happening. @Edric Thanks

Comment: None of these imports help me. The mat-select still renders outside of app-root. Using Angular 16

Answer (score 2):

You have to import `@import "~@angular/cdk/overlay-prebuilt.css";` in `styles.scss`.

Answer (score 0):

This can help you find the right path :

In the **app.component.html**, add a class to select `<mat-form-field>` tag :

```
<mat-form-field class="myForm">
```

At the bottom of **app.component.scss**

```
/*.navbar-default{
  height: 120px;
}*/

.myForm {
  height: 100px;
}

#cdk-overlay-2 > div {
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.page-content {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.main-page{
  height: 130px;
}
```